# Android Retrofit soap request envelope with security header

Tags: java, android, soap, retrofit2

I have written a soap request envelop class with security headers. I am using retrofit2 and its simplexml converter. Some how stuck to find problems in it. I am getting internal server error 500 while using below class. I have remove getter and setter so that question will be precise.

```
@Root(name = "soapenv")
@NamespaceList({
    @Namespace(prefix = "new", reference = "http://www.example.org/ClassViewRQST"),
    @Namespace(prefix = "soapenv", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
})
public class PeopleSoftRequest {

@Element(name = "soapenv:Header", required = false)
private PeopleSoftHeader header;

@Root(name = "soapenv:Header", strict = false)
public static class PeopleSoftHeader {

    @Element(name = "wsse:Security", required = false)
    private Security security;
}

@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(prefix = "mustUnderstand", reference = "1"),
        @Namespace(prefix = "wsse", reference = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")
})
@Root(name = "wsse:Security", strict = false)
public static class Security {

    @Element(name = "wsse:UsernameToken", required = false)
    private UserNameToken userNameToken;
}

@Root(name = "wsse:UsernameToken", strict = false)
public static class UserNameToken {
    @Element(name = "wsse:Username", required = false)
    private String username;

    @Namespace(prefix = "type", reference = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText")
    @Element(name = "wsse:Password", required = false)
    private String passWord;

}

@Element(name = "Body", required = false)
private PeopleSoftBody body;
}
```

Below is the raw soap request envelope for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:new="http://www.example.org/ClassViewRQST">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>XXXXXXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXXXXX</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>\n
<soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue. Below are the details...

The main issue is when the request soap is generating it's messing up with soap tag namespace prefix like

> request that was genrating

```
<type:wsse:Password xmlns:type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXXXXX</type:wsse:Password>
```

> correct request tag

```
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXXXXX</wsse:Password>
```

Genrating soap tag like above I have created below class while using attribute solve the problem

```
  public static class Password{
    @Text
    private String password;

    @Attribute(name = "Type")
    String Type = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText";

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```